# Unity3D: Manage messy code

Tags: unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I am writing my main manager script for my game. I seems like the script handles 10+ huge if..else..if..else statements. It looks messy and hard to manage. And in monodevelop I am not able to minimise particular parts of code like we can do in eclipse.

I am considering of creating individual script for each part and enable-access-disable it from a common script.

Please direct me to the better ways to do?

Comment: That is a bit broad to give you directions. You should narrow down what is your issue. You seem to ask for code design and there is too much to tell without any idea of your problem.

Comment: If any of the answers worked for you, it would be helpful for others if you accept that answer. If not, feel free to comment on the answers given, or update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the best case every method or class should have one responsibility, and only one.

- Try to extract duplicate code into methods
- Try to split up your classes, so that each class does only one thing
- Advanced: organize your classes in layers (Model-View-Control) and only talk to other classes through interfaces

Answer (score 1):

share some code structure. it is a good practice to encapsulate blocks of code that perform a particular task into functions that accept parameters,

eg ( `myFunction(param1, param2, param3){}` )

if you ever have to reuse the code block you merely call the function and have it return the necessary values.

Comment: Thank you Conceptz. I think I have done this pretty well. I think splitting up classes as Thomas said would be helpful.